# What do you call a situation that can end very well or very badly?

Tags: word-request

I am not sure if there's a word for this, but if there isn't, it would be really useful if we had a word for it since I can see many situation where the word would be used.

For example, let's look at this example sentence:

> I just want to roll the dice, because this is a ___ and I am a
>   gambling person. I am all in!

Comment: My suggestion is "open-end situation": it can end up very well or very badly, time will tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some possibilities, all from the Oxford Dictionaries:

> [**make or break**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make_or_break)
>   PHRASE
>   Be the factor which decides whether (something) will succeed or fail.
>   *I just want to roll the dice, because this is **make or break** and I am a gambling person.*
>
> [**life-or-death**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/life-or-death)
>   ADJECTIVE
>   That involves or is regarded as involving life and death; (by extension) extremely urgent or dangerous.
>   *I just want to roll the dice, because this is a **life-or-death** situation and I am a gambling person.*
>
> [**game changer**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/game_changer)
>   NOUN
>   An event, idea, or procedure that effects a significant shift in the current way of doing or thinking about something.
>   *I just want to roll the dice, because this is a **game changer** and I am a gambling person.*
>
> [**life-changing**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/life-changing)
>   ADJECTIVE
>   Having such a strong effect that it changes one's life.
>   *I just want to roll the dice, because this is **life-changing** and I am a gambling person.*

Answer (score 1):

There are many expressions but one is literally "a roll/toss of the dice".

> I have no idea if I got that job. I thought I did well on the interview but It's still a total **dice toss**.